# How do I send a parameter to a function from block?

Tags: url, parameter

This is my try:

```
$this->addTab( $grup_name, array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('netgroup_attributegrouping')->__($grup_name),
                'title'     => Mage::helper('netgroup_attributegrouping')->__($grup_name),
                'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('netgroup_attributegrouping/adminhtml_form_edit_tab_managegroup')->toHtml(), //calea catre block
                'url'=> $this->getUrl('*/*/index/' ,array('active_tab' => $grup_name))
));
```

is it possible that somehow to send a parameter to a a function from a block  using the **url** attribute from **tabs** ? Or is the an other way ?

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a tab either by specifying the exact block

```
'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('netgroup_attributegrouping/adminhtml_form_edit_tab_managegroup')->toHtml(),
```

In this case you can pass a parameter to the block before calling `toHtml()`.

```
'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('netgroup_attributegrouping/adminhtml_form_edit_tab_managegroup')->setSomeValue($valueHere)->toHtml(),
```

or if it's an ajax tab you specify the url in which case you can just pass a parameter in the url

```
'url'=> $this->getUrl('*/*/index/' ,array('param_name'=>$paramValue))
```

You cannot have a tab that is generated from both, content and url.
**[EDIT]**
If you are using the url approach, you can read the value sent through the url in your controller like this:

```
$value = $this->getRequest()->getParam('param_name'); 
//or
$value = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('param_name');
```

Comment: thx for  the quick answer, but how can i get this parameter in index ?

Comment: @Chester. See my edit. Is that what you need?

Comment: yep, thx for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Chester,As per as code `,you have  wrote something wrong`,

```
You can use either  'content'tab or 'url'
```

`'content'` is give content of `a tab without using ajax.`

'`url' is give content of tabs with using ajax from  other pages`.
According to Marius ,whenever you want fetch data from directly then use

```
'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('netgroup_attributegrouping/adminhtml_form_edit_tab_managegroup')->toHtml(),
```

This code provide the tabs details on  basic of current url.`Do not fetch from $this->getUrl('*/*/index',array('_current'=>true,active_tab' => $grup_name))` url

else you want to tab data from ajax  other url then you need parameter

```
$this->addTab($grup_name,array(
        'label'=>Mage::helper('netgroup_attributegrouping')->__($grup_name),,
        'title'     => Mage::helper('netgroup_attributegrouping')->__($grup_name),
        'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/index',array('_current'=>true,active_tab' => $grup_name)),
        'class'=>'ajax'
        ));
```